# Angularjs and ui-grid - add event keypress in cell

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

First of all, I want to say that I am beginner with angularjs :D

***My problem is:***

I'm trying add the keypress event when user goes to edit the value in cell on angular ui-grid.

In the beginning it seems to work, but when I finish editing a cell and mute the focus the value disappears.

***Here is the link to see the event running:*** https://plnkr.co/edit/vw8W6PqFt11nt4BDhWu9

And here is my code:

***File: index.html***

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/v3.0.6/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/v3.0.6/ui-grid.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit class="grid"></div>
</div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

***File: app.js***

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit']);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: [{
        field: 'name'
      }, {
        field: 'amount',
        name: 'Number'
      }, {
        field: 'someValue',
        name: 'SomeValue',
        editableCellTemplate: 'template-cell.html'
      }]
    };

    $http.get('data.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
      });
  }]);

  app.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
      return {
          require: 'ngModel',
          link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
              function fromUser(text) {
                  if (text) {
                      var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/, '');

                      if (transformedInput !== text) {
                          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                          ngModelCtrl.$render();
                      }
                      return transformedInput;
                  }
                  return undefined;
              }            
              ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
          }
      };
  });
}());
```

***File: cell-template.html***

```
<div>
  <form name="inputForm">
    <input type="text" 
           ui-grid-editor 
           ng-model="someValue" 
           data="row.entity.someValue"
           ng-class="'colt' + col.uid" 
           numbers-only />
  </form>
</div>
```

**I need this functionality with keypress event only.** How do I update the model with the input field value ?

Thanks.

Comment: can't you just use `type="number"` instead to allow only numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your column value is not correctly bound to the ngModel in the cell template.

The correct value would be to use the MODEL_COL_FIELD which you can read more about in the [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Templating), look at section "Editable Cell Templates"

Update your cell-template.html to

```
<div>
  <form name="inputForm">
    <input type="text" 
           ui-grid-editor 
           ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" 
           ng-class="'colt' + col.uid" 
           numbers-only />
  </form>
</div>
```